# IE 7 conditional comments not working

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, conditional-comments

My conditional style sheet for IE 7 is not working. I've looked into a bunch of reasons this may not be working and i just can't figure it out. I've tried all kinds of things to test it, perhaps i'm overlooking something obvious but i sure hope not!

To test the issue I've set up the conditional style sheet (custom.css) to hide the blurb of text at the top of the home page: http://learnfrombuildings.com/ - but it's still there! if i  insert the same snippet of code into the main style sheet, it does the intended job. but in the ie7-targeted style sheet, it does zilch (I am using ie7 to view it, not ie8 compatibility mode).

Would greatly appreciate your feedback on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the comment:

From
    `<!--[if IE 7]`

to
    `<!--[if IE 7]>`

Comment: Perfect, Kellie! Btw: Would you mind accepting the answer? :-)